# facebook webhook url error has been identified as malicious and/or abusive

Tags: facebook-webhooks

We are testing facebook messenger with our bot. Few months back we were able
to configure ngrok url over facebook.developer as callback webhook url, but not its giving error as "The url https://xyz.in.ngrok.io/webhook has been identified as malicious and/or abusive.."

Any solution so we can use ngrok for testing before we provide production url.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook seems to have blocked some of the ngork domains, US is still active.

To switch over to the US region, add this param: `--region us`

Example: `ngrok http 7071 --region us`

Issue on GitHub: https://github.com/inconshreveable/ngrok/issues/427